# inversion of coefficients in taylor expansion

Tags: taylor-expansion

There are two different functions, one has ArcSin x multiplied or divided by some function of x as for example the square of (1-x^2) or x itself. The other function is only a power of (1-x^2).  x goes from 0 to 1  excluded.
The fact is that when I expand in series around x=0, the first function has a development  of the kind  a0 + a2 x^2+ a4 x^4 +... with all the even powers.
The other function has a development such as
(1/a0)+ (1/a2) x^2+ (1/a4) x^4+ ... i.e. same structure of the power series but ALL the infinite coefficients are for one function the reciprocal of the other function.
I think that's not possible such a coincidence for two functions that seems just arbitrarily different one from te other, there should be some relation between the two functions. Someone knows if there is any relation between two functions whose development has all the coefficients different from zero one reciprocal of the other?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: it is simple: Let's consider two functions that are expanded in taylor series around 0 and the expansions are identical if one substitute all the coefficients of the expansion of one of the functions with their reciprocal, i.e. for example the coefficient of the fourth power of one function is 45/128 and the coefficient of the fourth power of the other function is 128/45 an so on for ALL the coefficients. I'm asking if there is a functional relationship between the two functions. i.e, one function is the inverse of the other (it is not true but it is an example of relationship between them)